# Apple Watch no longer displays heart rate after watchOS update

Tags: apple-watch, watchos

Yesterday I updated my Apple Watch to watchOS 5.2.1 and ever since my Heart Rate complication has stopped displaying my heart rate on the watch face. I can still tap it and measure my heart rate, but it’s not displayed on the watch face.

Is this a new 'feature' of watchOS? If not, how do I fix it?

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :)  I hope you come to find this site has a lot to offer! In case you haven't already, it's worth taking the time to read the [tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1. The first thing to do is make sure that Background App Refresh is still enabled, and if so, enabled for Heart Rate.**

To do this:

1. On your iPhone open the Watch app
2. Swipe up and tap on General
3. Tap on Background App Refresh
4. Make sure Background App Refresh is enabled at top of screen
5. Swipe up to check that the Heart Rate option is enabled

**2. If Background App Refresh was already enabled, or if enabling it still didn’t do the trick, then double-check you haven’t got Power Saving Mode enabled.**

To do this:

1. On your Apple Watch open the Settings app
2. Swipe up and tap on General
3. Swipe up and tap on Workout
4. Swipe up and ensure that Power Saving Mode is disabled

**3. Finally, if this doesn’t resolve it, fully reboot your Apple Watch.**

To do this:

1. Press and hold both the crown and side button until you see the Apple logo appear on screen
2. Wait for your watch to reboot
3. Check your heart rate complication is displaying your heart rate

Comment: None of those worked for me.  Does heart rate just not work on certain faces?  Like, does it require a large section or can it be displayed in a corner?